# How many quirks does All for One have?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In the battle with All Might , All for One shows many quirks he has. Since I understand this is the last fight of All for One, are all his quirks shown in this battle? Is it known how many quirks does All for One have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/All_For_One) All for One has between 21 to 28 **Quirks**:

> 1. All For One
> 2. Search
> 3. Warping
> 4. Air Cannon
> 5. Springlike Limbs
> 6. Forcible Quirk Activation
> 7. Impact Recoil
> 8. Infrared Ray
> 9. Air Walk
> 10. Longevity
> 11. Proliferation
> 12. Hypertrophy
> 13. Rivet
> 14. Bonespear
>
> There is Four Kinetic Booster Quirks and three Strength Enhancement
>   Quirks. (the wiki only mentions this)
>
> It is also possible that he possessed some, if not all of following
>   Quirks:
>
> 22. Absorption and Release
> 23. Tongue Web
> 24. Muscle Enlargement
> 25. Pterodactyl
> 26. Tool Arms
> 27. Shock Absorption
> 28. Super Regeneration